# When doing a mercurial clone over http, I get a 500 error

Tags: mercurial, clone

I set up a repository on another computer for which I want to start cloning over http.  I set up apache with the directive as stated below, and in the directory I have my index.cgi file as provided by mercurial.  I can clone a repository just fine if it's empty, but if it contains files, I get a 500 error.  Looking at the error logs, I see the following:

malformed header from script. Bad header=1 changesets found: index.cgi

To me, this sounds like a permissions issue, but everything is 775 (we're behind several firewalls) and everything is accessable from index.cgi over a browser.

I'm out of options, is there anything I'm missing?

Apache config:

```
Alias /hg /base/src/hg_cgi
<Directory "/base/src/hg_cgi">
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

Turns out that commenting out the following line in ~/.hgrc

```
#verbose = True
```

fixed things.

Source: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue1250

Comment: +1, same problem here. I wish I had read this post an hour ago :(

Answer (score 1):

I am using ScriptAlias, renamed hgweb.cgi to index.cgi, do not have verbose turned on but still see the 500 Internal server error.

With

```
hg clone http://ip.address.here:8880/hg/Lavanya2/test/ .
```

I get in Apache

```
[Wed Jul 28 11:52:27 2010] [error] [client ip.address.here] malformed header from script. Bad header=8 changesets found: index.cgi
```

Comment: I got this to work (finally!). I had to remove the debug=true setting from the hgrc file of the repository that I am trying to clone.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing that 'Alias' to a 'ScriptAlias'

Also, check your apache error log.  It will have more and better output.

Comment: I did the Alias -> ScriptAlias, no change.

Apache logs indicate "malformed header from script. Bad header=1 changesets found: index.cgi"

Comment: Try doing a script alias all the way to the CGI.  It's safer too:

    ScriptAlias /base/src/hg_cgi/hgwebdir.cgi

Also what was in the apache error log?  That's where the money is.

Comment: Apache error log shows "malformed header from script. Bad header=1 changesets found: index.cgi"  That's it

Comment: What did you rename to index.cgi?  Was it hgweb.cgi or hgwebdir.cgi?  What URL are you using to push/pull in this scenario?  Maybe try `--debug` when you clone and see if there's anything interesting there?